# What function provides an upper bound?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I made a line of the positive integers and then underneath each integer I made a line of the primes. I circled every pair of numbers that were both prime.

1, **2**, **3**, 4, **5**, 6, **7**

2, **3**, **5**, 7, **11**, 13, **17**

I then counted the spaces in between the pairs.

For example there is a pair of numbers, namely $4$ and $7$ in between two prime pairs, namely $3$ and $5$ and $5$ and $11.$ So I counted this gap between prime pairs as $1$ unit.

The first few terms in the sequence of gaps is $g=(1,1,1,3,...)$

After getting the sequence of gaps between prime pairs I plotted them as vertical heights such as:

$(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,3),(5,1),(6,3,),(7,1),(8,3,),(9,5),(10,1),(11,5),... $

Plotting these points, I noticed that a logarithm function might bound the set of points from above.

How do I find the exact function? I think it is $f(x)=e\ln(x),$ for $x>1.$

[image]

Comment: Can you explain better how you got those pairs? Maybe use an example? I still don't get it. Maybe if you explain formally how you get the first and second coordinate would be nice.

Comment: Yes I will be doing that soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you want to bound P(P(n))-P(n), where the function P gives the nth prime.

Of course, P(P(n)-P(n) works. But perhaps you meant an elementary function. Well we know that $\frac{n}{log(n)}$ ~ P(n), so you could approximate your function with $\frac{\frac{n}{log(n)}}{log\left(\frac{n}{log(n)}\right)}-\frac{n}{log(n)}$.